# How to write Junit 5 test cases for Spring integration dsl configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, junit5, spring-integration-dsl

Here I'm using Scatter-gather pattern and calling 3 sub-flows parallelly. Then gathering them and aggregating them. I need to write junit test cases for the configuration class, gateway and controller. I'm new to Spring Integration so kindly help me with this.

The code is as follows -

//Configuration class

```
 @Configuration
    public class IntegrationConfiguration {
      @Autowired LoansServiceImpl loansService;
    
      long dbId = new SequenceGenerator().nextId();
  //   Main flow
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.split()
            .log()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .convert(LoanProvisionRequest.class)
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.releaseLockBeforeSend(true))
            .log()
            .aggregate(a -> a.outputProcessor(MessageGroup::getMessages))
            .channel("output-flow");
  }
  //   flow1
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message -> {
                  try {
                    lionService.saveLionRequest(
                        (LionRequest) message.getPayload(), String.valueOf(dbId));
                  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  }
                });
  }

  //   flow2
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow2() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message ->
                    lionService.getData(
                        (LionRequest) message.getPayload(), SourceSystem.PROVISION))
            .log();
  }

  //  flow3
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow3() {
    return integrationFlowDefination ->
        integrationFlowDefination
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .handle(
                message ->
                    lionService.prepareCDRequest(
                        (LionRequest) message));
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel replyChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.executor("output-flow", outputExecutor()).get();
  }

  @Bean
  public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor outputExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(4);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(4);
    return pool;
  }
}
```

//Gateway interface

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface LionGateway {

  @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input", replyChannel = "output-flow")
  List<?> echo(LionRequest lionRequest);
}
```

//Controller class

```
@Autowired private LionGateway lionGateway;

 @PostMapping(value = "/invoke-integration")
  public String invokeIntegrationFlow(@RequestBody LionRequest lionRequest) {
    String response = lionGateway.echo(lionRequest).toString();
    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in the `@Configuration` testing: it just registers beans. So, you probably need just concentrate on the interaction with those beans in your tests.

The `Controller` you can test via MockMvc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework.

Probably the `@MessagingGateway` could be just covered with the controller testing since it looks like you just call it from that `@PostMapping` method.

To test Spring Integration endpoints you need to decide how granualy you'd like to go. But probably our Testing Framework with the `MockIntegration` can help you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context